# How to use template and OOP in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, struct

I wish to perform operations on a set of structs such as addition, like the example below. The program gives an error, `no match for 'operator+' (operand types are 'Gravity' and 'Friction')`. How can I implement it correctly?

```
#ifndef FORCE_HPP
#define FORCE_HPP

struct Physics{    // not sure if this is needed

  struct Gravity{   // force type 1, which computes gravity

    int operator()(double t) {   //gravity force is computed based on a parameter t, and returns an int
        ...
        return Fg;
    }
};

  struct Friction{    // force type 2, which computes friction

    int operator()(double t) {   //friction force is computed based on parameter t, and returns an int
        ...
        return Fs;
    }
};

  template< typename F1, typename F2>
  Point make_physics(F1 first, F2 second){   // there can be 2 gravity forces, 2 friction forces, or 1 gravity and 1 friction force in a problem. As a result, use a template
    return first + second;
  }

};
#endif
```

If the program works correctly, when I do the following

```
int main(){
...
make_pair(t, make_physics(Gravity(), Friction()) );
...
}
```

I should get a pair of time and the force computed for that time.

Comment: Your auto-casts have the wrong template. Think about it; to cast, you have zero parameters and return the type that you want to cast to. Unrelatedly, what *do* you get when you add Gravity to Friction? It sounds like your concepts are screwy. Consider using Force instead, and you can just typedef it to a double or double[3]...

Comment: More information about your code needed, I think.  At least a compilable version.

Comment: Please add comments about what the lines are intended to do. In particular is Dave correct that `operator()` is intended to do a cast? That's the function-call operator, not the cast. You might be looking for `operator double()` but it's unclear how you want `int` to relate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no OOP there, and you never mentioned what the program is supposed to do. But running in the most obvious direction and applying quick fixes,

```
#ifndef FORCE_HPP
#define FORCE_HPP

namespace Physics{ // use a namespace, not an unusable struct

  struct Force { // OOP base class for various forces
    double value; // one dimension for now

    operator double () { // implicitly convert to a scalar equal to magnitude
      return value;
    }
  };

  struct Gravity : public Force {
  };

  struct Friction : public Force {
  };

  template< typename F1, typename F2>
  double add_scalars(F1 first, F2 second){ 
    return first + second; // sort of pointless, but there you have it
  }

}
#endif
```